# Thread safe access to collection from UITableViewSource in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I use `ObservableCollection` to store data (this is needed as it is used for data binding in the UWP project). As `ObservableCollection` is not thread safe, I use `SemaphoreSlim` to ensure that only one thread has access to it.

In nearly all cases this works except for the `UITableViewSource`. The problem appears if I implement both `EstimatedHeight` and `GetHeightForRow` - as both of those need access to the collection it appears that there is some conflict and application becomes fairly unresponsive. I would assume that there is some level of concurrency among those tasks.

Right now I have decided to put the `SemaphoreSlim` in only one method and to risk some rare crashes and the app is working properly, but I am quite sure there should be some way to safely access those values. Anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: As far as I get you are using ObservableCollection in order your data to get updated on the UI as soon as it was changed. Am I correct?

Comment: @Gleb yes, but in this particular case I don't think it is necessary for reproducing the issue, I think everything needed is mentioned above.

Comment: well you can only update your UI from the main thread. It means that you can only Add / Remove items from your collection inside one single thread. So how is it isn't thread safe in your case?

Comment: @Gleb, I agree that one likely solution is to move all operations with this collection to UI thread, though it should also include the case when the collection is assigned as it can also be assigned not just that members can be added and removed and finally other cases when it is accessed that don't necessarily need to be on the UI thread by default. You can post as the answer I'll definitely upvote it.

Comment: Idl why but I thought that we are discussing UWP. I've deleted my answer. Sorry for the misunderstanding.